# Moving messages from dead letter back to topic

Tags: java, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

**Background:**

I can read messages from a Dead Letter Queue of a subscription. I gather them in a `List` and set `receiver.complete(message.getLockToken())`, which removes the message from DLQ.

And later on, I iterate through this list of gathered messages from DLQ and send them back to topic. At the time of putting them into a `List`, I do make sure that I create a new object of Message (or BrokeredMessage) before putting it in.

This is all well and good for my own personal account. I see numbers go up. I can also read them fine in another method.

**Problem:**

I don't know where the messages are ending up when I connect to my company's Topic? They don't go to any subscription. And I don't see any number going up (active count, dead letter count, etc).

**Question:**

Could this be because no rule is able to process those messages, so they are auto purged? Is this a possibility?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you setup the Comapny topic?

Comment: @AresOu, hello, thank you for looking into my question. I think I got some of it figured out myself. Thanks though.

Comment: Please write down your findings in answer section and accept it as it will help others in the community.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT - done. thanks

Comment: To answer your question, the same would happen as if you had no subscriptions. Refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613216/messages-sent-to-topic-are-getting-lost-if-no-subscriptions-are-specified) for more details.

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT thank you. It answers my question.

Comment: I found this comment in my code...maybe it applies :             /* Microsoft does NOT support moving the message to a subscription directly :(
             * https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/9295470-resubmit-dead-letter-message-back-to-the-subscript 
             * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096262/send-message-directly-to-subscription

             */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is trivial and is already spread across stackoverflow.

When I was making a new message object `new Message(oldMessage)`, it was copying all the properties from the old message including `DeadLetterReason` and  `DeadLetterErrorDescription`. You can get properties by calling this message `msg.getProperties()`.

This is the reason why messages were going into the ether. I stopped it from copying over, and this resolved the issue.

On a side note, I have found the answer to my actual question on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613216/messages-sent-to-topic-are-getting-lost-if-no-subscriptions-are-specified) as suggested by [@PramodValavala-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10417839/pramodvalavala-msft)

This was my original question: Could this be because no rule is able to process those messages, so they are auto purged? Is this a possibility?